# mlflow not work after installation (Ubuntu 16, Centos 7)

Tags: ubuntu, centos, gunicorn, mlflow

[image: enter link description here]

I try to install and run the web-based interface mlflow on VM Azure Ubuntu 16 and Centos 7.
After running the command:
sudo mlflow ui

I can not get access url, either through the dns (mydomain.com:5000), or by IP: http://123.456.789.123:5000/

Executing on the server:

wget http://localhost:5000

I get the html-page mlflow, ie the server is running, but then why can not I connect to it in a browser? - Error:The connection has timed out

p.s. Firewall disabled on this VM.

Answer (score 0):

The server listens only on the 127.0.0.1 email address (localhost) by default, so you should be able to access it through that address from your machine, but not through any other address. If you want it to listen on another address, add `--host <address>` to your command line. Note that anyone with access to that IP address will be able to view/edit runs, so keep that on a private network (that's why the server only listens on localhost by default).